Why does computer slow down when inactive?
I am running a computationally intensive program that will take some time to complete. I have divided the task into many separate Windows console programs, which are equivalent except for the starting values. I have four machines which I have dedicated to the task.

A custom built desktop using an Asus 'Supercomputer' motherboard

An MSI gaming laptop

A Monster gaming laptop

An Asus Strix Scar 17 laptop
all running Windows 10.


I run one program for each thread on a machine, which is easier for me than trying to learn how to write a single multi-threaded program.
Now, my three oldest computers all run approximately the same number of calculations per thread per second. But, ironically, the Asus laptop, which is my newest and most powerful computer, only does about half what that the rest are doing. I was initially thinking maybe it is being throttled due to heat. But whenever I looked at task manager the CPU speed was always at maximum. Eventually, though, I noticed that after some specific time away, between 4 and 5 minutes, the Performance graphs show that the CPU utilization drops from 100% to 25%. As soon as I interact with the computer again (i.e. mouse movement) the utilization immediately goes up to 100%. So the problem is obviously not thermal, because it can't magically cool down and go back to normal speed the instant I start using it every time. My other 3 computers have all the same settings but stay at 100%, regardless of whether I am interacting with them or not.
The only thing I can think of is that this must be some kind of 'feature' that reduces power or something if no interaction is detected for 5 minutes, or whatever. I have searched for any kind of setting that could be related to this but have found nothing. I did stop as many processes and services as I could before I started running the programs, so the environment should be as unencumbered as possible. I have looked through all Windows power and other settings and some Asus utilities that came installed, but nothing seems to be relevant, and they're not running in the background anyway.
Does anyone have any idea what's going on or how I can diagnose the issue?

"I have looked through all Windows settings and through some Asus utilities ..." - What about BIOS/UEFI settings?
